# </a> tag cut off when creating article preview

Tags: php, html, anchor, trim

Hi,
I'm creating custom CMS. On the homepage, I want to have a list of all articles, with first ~80 words of the article shown. I'm trying to figure out how to get the article preview.

Problem is that if I cut it in the middle of an `<a>` tag (so it will look like this: `<a href="blahblah">...[closing tag is cut off]`), the rest of the page will be treated as content of the link.

How to deal with this?

Comment: Don't trim it in the middle of an anchor.

Comment: @relentless: That could cause the result to be significantly than 80 words, violating the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maintain a stack of opening tags seen so far, and then pop off the corresponding closing tags when the trimmed summary is complete.